# How do I add a calculated field based on the sum/count in a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have some data that is basically just identifier and timestamp.  What I want to do is, using Excel and Pivot Tables to get a listing of identifiers, broken down by date, with a count of rows of data for that date and then a calculation on that count; in particular I expect 256 for each count and I want to take that count divide by 285 and get "percentage completed".

I have the data in excel 2016; I did a calculated field on the timestamp (Date.For(Timestamp)) to get the date; I have a pivot table with the rows: identifier; datestamp and values: count of datestamp

I need to then add a column to the pivot table that takes the "count of datestamp" and divides it by 285.  All I've been able to find is row-level calculated fields, but cannot find a way to access the count (aggregate value) and divide at that level.

I've attempted to name that count column and use Analyze > Fields, Items, Sets > Calculated Field ... but that count column isn't in the options and if I type it in I get an error on the calculation.

Feels like it is something very straight forward, but I'm just missing something.

Comment: I don't think you can do calculations on aggregated value in the same PivotTable, but should be possible with Power Query/PowerPivot

Comment: I have access to both of those (Power Query/PowerPivot) with Excel 2016; how would that be done there?

Comment: not sure because I don't have Excel at home, but should be easy to learn https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-rows-in-a-table-Power-Query-e1b9e916-6fcc-40bf-a6e8-ef928240adf1

Comment: humm... power query runs out of memory on the group by process (i.e. the data that the pivot table has calculated); i wonder if there is just some simple way to do that calculation on the pivot table since it doesn't seem to be as memory intensive

Comment: I was expecting Power Query to be able to handle much more data than PivotTable, because it should convert the query to SQL internally, but I guess it loads all the data in memory if the query and data source are in the same workbook. The only other possible workarounds I can think of is to try the power query in a separate workbook after closing and saving the data source workbook, or to use the PivotTable as a data source for another PivotTable. As a final resort there is also VBA.

Comment: I'm using Azure Table Storage as the data source (so maybe that is the reason for memory constraints) ... I've gone to C# (console application) to call the Azure Table Storage and output to an excel document :( ... Shame, really thought something like this would fall into the wheel house of excel

Comment: The basic idea is to get the entire table count into each row. Then you can easily calculate on a row level. So, when importing the data with Power Pivot you can create a new `measure` with `DAX` in `Power Pivot` doing this and then calculate on a row level.